# Slick column mapper java.sql.Time to Joda LocalTime

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick

Looking to map java.sql.time to some joda time class. Having some issues with the mapper, it throws an error message. Has anyone performed this conversion?

```
trait DateMapper {
  implicit val DateMapper =
    MappedColumnType .base[java.sql.Time, org.joda.time.LocalTime] (
      d => new LocalTime(d.getTime))

}
```

Error

```
Unspecified value parameters: tcomap:(LocalTime) => Time
```

Comment: What's the error msg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing the `LocalTime => Time` conversion for `ResultSet -> Scala Collection` conversion:

```
MappedColumnType.base[java.sql.Time, org.joda.time.LocalTime] (
  time => new LocalTime(time.getTime),
  localTime => new Time(localTime.toDateTimeToday().getMillis()))
```